# css alignemet issue display the text in one line

Tags: css, html

Please visit these sites :

here you can usually deliver in 3-5 days is displaying in 2 lines

I want to display that in one line as in this link :

Comment: Just because a site is made in Magento, doesn't make all questions regarding it relevant to this site. You should post this question at http://stackoverflow.com, you'll have better chances of finding the answer there.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @Prateek , my ip blocked in stackoverflow.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with what @Prateek has said here but you are missing styles for the `.Delivery`. It looks like the styles have been added to the template rather than a stylesheet which is why on some products the styles work and some it doesn't. You are better off moving any styles have have been added to a template and add them to a css file that way the site will have consistent styling.